# Install plzip on Redhat Enterprise Linux Server

Tags: installation, redhat

I'm fairly new to linux so when yum install doesn't work, I'm lost. I found some files online for plzip but I don't know how to install the program from those files.

Comment: Does it have to be plzip or any multithreded compression program?

Comment: Another program could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install plzip you will most likely have to download the source code in tarball, uncompress and compile it. (usually: ./configure; make; make install) but as RHEL is RPM based your life will be much easier (for now) if you stick to what's available in RPM or in fact what was shipped with your distribution.

If I'm not mistaken you want to use multiple threads to compress you data. If you are on RHEL 5 or 6 you should have `xz` available to you:

```
yum install xz
```

From Wikipedia:

> XZ Utils (previously LZMA Utils) is a set of free command-line
>   lossless data compressors, including LZMA and xz, for Unix-like
>   operating systems and, from version 5.0 onwards, Microsoft Windows.

From `man xz`

> DESCRIPTION
>          xz  is  a  general-purpose  data compression tool with command line syntax similar to gzip(1) and bzip2(1).  The native file format
>   is the .xz format, but also the legacy .lzma format and raw
>          compressed streams with no container format headers are supported.

In other words this is an implementation of Lempel-Zif-Markov algorithm and by far most popular tool to use it is 7zip. To read more about it you can visit great Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm

The other option would be to use pbzip - which is also available in rpm: http://compression.ca/pbzip2/ and by it looks of things it might make it to RHEL one day...

Comment: That is very helpful. I think it will work. I'm still unclear how to specify the filename to save it as. This is what I have for plzip: "/usr/bin/mysqldump -h $DBHOST -u $DBUSER -p$DBPASS --quick --single-transaction $db | /usr/local/bin/plzip -n$THREADS_TO_USE -o $db_file_path". The only thing I can't figure out is what to do with that "-o". I do need to specify the name and location.

Comment: First of all I would say to move U/P to the file and lock it down so you will not have that in your cron/email/history! Unfortunately, compressors are just that - compressors. Fortunately, you have option of `xz --stdout`  which then can be redirected to the file you want.

Comment: Like this then? `/usr/bin/mysqldump -h $DBHOST -u $DBUSER -p$DBPASS --quick --single-transaction $db | /usr/local/bin/xz -T$THREADS_TO_USE --stdout > $db_file_path`